# How to inject svg into svg? Embedded svgs

Tags: html, svg

Cannot find the way to inject svg to svg:
Here code sample where I want to see yellow circle when hovering `19` number

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 680 183">
   <defs>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-seat" viewBox="-10 -9.5 20 19">
         <path stroke="#5E6870" d="M5.5-7h-12c-1.7 0-3 1.3-3 3v8c0 1.7 1.3 3 3 3H5.6L5.5-7z"></path>
         <path fill="#C6CBCF" stroke="#5E6870" d="M7.5 7a2 2 0 002-2V-5a2 2 0 00-2-2h-2V7h2zM5.5 7h-11a2 2 0 002 2h7a2 2 0 002-2zM5.5-7h-11a2 2 0 012-2h7a2 2 0 012 2z"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-seatrot" viewBox="-17.4 -9 34.9 17.9">
         <path fill="none" stroke="#3385B3" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M14.5 6.6C14.5-1.4 8-8 0-8S-14.5-1.4-14.5 6.6"></path>
         <path fill="#3385B3" d="M-17.4 6l2.9 3 2.9-3zM11.6 6l2.9 3 2.9-3z"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-luggage" viewBox="-12.5 -11 25 22">
         <path d="M-11.5 7c-.7-.6-1-2-1-2.9V-7.8c0-.9.3-1.6 1-2.3.6-.6 1-.9 1.9-.9h.9V8H-10c-.9 0-.9-.4-1.5-1zM3.4 8h-6.8v1.5h6.8V8zm1.5.7c0 1.3-1 2.3-2.3 2.3h-5.3C-4 11-5 10-5 8.7V8h-2.3v-18.9H7.2V8H4.9v.8zM11.5 7c-.6.6-1.8.9-2.7.9h-.1v-18.3l.9-.6c.9 0 1.3.3 1.9.9.6.6 1 1.4 1 2.3V4.1c0 .9-.3 2.3-1 2.9z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-wardrobe" viewBox="-14.2 -10 28.4 20">
         <path d="M0-.4L-11.3-5c-.7-.3-1.1-1.3-1.1-2 0-.9.8-1.7 1.7-1.7h21.4c1 0 1.7.8 1.7 1.7 0 .7-.4 1.7-1.1 2L0-.4zM10.7-10h-21.4c-1.9 0-3.5 1.5-3.5 3.4 0 1.4 1.1 2.7 2.4 3.2L-.7 1.1v3h.9c1.2 0 1.9.9 1.9 2.1 0 1.2-1 2-2.1 2-1.2 0-2.1-.9-2.1-2.1h-1.8c0 2.1 1.7 3.8 3.9 3.8 2.1 0 3.7-1.5 3.7-3.6 0-1.8-1.3-3.3-3-3.7V1.1l11.1-4.5c1.3-.5 2.4-1.8 2.4-3.2 0-1.9-1.6-3.4-3.5-3.4z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-conf" viewBox="-24 -64.4 44 20.6">
         <path d="M-3.5-45.5c-2-2-2-5.2 0-7.2 1.7-1.7 4.2-1.9 6.2-.8.8-.6 1.6-.7 2.2-.6.2 0 .2.3.1.4-.5.3-.9.8-1 1.2h.1c1.8 2 1.7 5.1-.2 7-2.2 2-5.4 2-7.4 0zm5.9-4.2c-.3 0-.6.3-.6.6s.3.6.6.6.6-.3.6-.6-.3-.6-.6-.6zm-2.3 0c-.3 0-.6.3-.6.6s.3.6.6.6.6-.3.6-.6-.3-.6-.6-.6zm-2.3 0c-.3 0-.6.3-.6.6s.3.6.6.6.6-.3.6-.6-.3-.6-.6-.6z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
         <path d="M1.9-60.3c-.4-.4-.7-.9-.7-1.4v-2.7h8.2l.8 3.7c-1.6 2.3.1 2.4.4 2.4.3 0 2.1-.1.4-2.4l.8-3.7H20v2.7c0 .6-.3 1.1-.7 1.4-2.4 2-5 3.3-5.5 3.5-.1 0-.1.1-.1.2v3.7c.5.3.8.9.8 1.5v3.9c0 1.9-1.6 3.5-3.5 3.5h-.8c-1.9 0-3.5-1.6-3.5-3.5v-3.9c0-.6.3-1.1.8-1.5v-3.7c0-.1 0-.1-.1-.2-.5-.2-3.1-1.5-5.5-3.5z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
         <path d="M-.4-45.5c-2 2-5.2 2-7.2 0-1.9-1.9-2-5-.2-7h.1c-.2-.4-.5-.9-1-1.2-.2-.1-.1-.3.1-.4.6-.1 1.4 0 2.2.6h0c2-1.1 4.5-.9 6.2.8 1.8 2 1.8 5.2-.2 7.2z" fill="#fff" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#3385b3"></path>
         <path d="M-5.8-60.3c-2.4 2-5 3.3-5.5 3.5-.1 0-.1.1-.1.2v3.7c.5.3.8.9.8 1.5v3.9c0 1.9-1.6 3.5-3.5 3.5h-.8c-1.9 0-3.5-1.6-3.5-3.5v-3.9c0-.6.3-1.1.8-1.5v-3.7c0-.1 0-.1-.1-.2-.5-.3-3.1-1.6-5.5-3.5-.4-.4-.7-.9-.7-1.4v-2.7h8.2l.8 3.7c-1.6 2.3.1 2.4.4 2.4.3 0 2.1-.1.4-2.4l.8-3.7h8.2v2.7c0 .6-.2 1.1-.7 1.4z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
         <path d="M-6.3-48.5c.3 0 .6-.3.6-.6s-.3-.6-.6-.6-.6.3-.6.6.3.6.6.6zM-4-48.5c.3 0 .6-.3.6-.6s-.3-.6-.6-.6-.6.3-.6.6.3.6.6.6zM-1.7-48.5c.3 0 .6-.3.6-.6s-.3-.6-.6-.6-.6.3-.6.6.3.6.6.6z" fill="#fff" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#3385b3"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-exit" viewBox="-6.3 -8.7 12.7 17.3">
         <path fill="#3385B4" d="M-2.5 2.3h-3.8L0 8.7l6.3-6.3H2.5v-11h-5V2.3z"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-table" viewBox="-7 -16.5 14 33">
         <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#C6CBCF" d="M0 15.5c2.5 0 6-2 6-4v-27H-6v27c0 1.9 3.5 4 6 4z"></path>
      </symbol>
      <style>.scheme_91s_svg__s-cell{cursor:pointer}.scheme_91s_svg__cell-back{fill:#fff;stroke:none}text{font-family:Tahoma;font-weight:700;font-size:8px;fill:#807e7e}</style>
   </defs>
   <path fill="none" stroke="#C6CBCF" d="M247.5 56.6v70.8M208.5 56.6v70.8"></path>
   <path d="M94 92.7c0 21.2 0 27.6-7.5 27.6-12 0-51.5-2-51.5-27.6C35 68 71 65.1 86.5 64.9c7.5 0 7.5 6.4 7.5 27.8zM11.9 107c-1.5-1.5-2.7-6.8-3.1-8.4 1.6.7 7.1 3.1 14.4 5.7 1.1 1.8 5.1 6.9 6.4 8.8-3.1-.8-15.5-3.7-17.7-6.1zm18.8 6.6v-.2c-.2 0-5.8-7.5-6.9-9.5l-.2-.2c-8.8-2.9-15.2-5.9-15.2-5.9h-.2L8 98c0 .4 1.5 7.5 3.3 9.5 2.9 2.7 18.3 6.2 19 6.4l.4-.2v-.1zM11.7 77.4c2.2-2.4 14.6-5.3 17.9-6-1.5 1.8-5.5 6.9-6.4 8.8-7.3 2.6-13 4.9-14.6 5.7.3-1.8 1.6-7.1 3.1-8.5zm11.7 3.3l.2-.2c1.1-2 6.8-9.3 6.9-9.5v-.4h-.4c-.5 0-16.1 3.5-18.8 6.2-1.8 2-3.3 9.1-3.5 9.5l.2.2.2.2c.2-.2 6.4-3.1 15.2-6z" fill="#C6CBCF"></path>
   <path d="M74.1 122.1c0-.2 0-.2-.2-.2-15.5 0-51.7-10.1-51.7-29.2 0-18.6 34.1-29.1 51.7-29.2.2 0 .2-.2.2-.4s0-.2-.2-.2c-14.4 0-52.2 9.5-52.2 29.8 0 19.6 36.5 29.8 52.2 29.8.2 0 .2-.2.2-.4z" fill="#C6CBCF"></path>
   <path d="M195.5 46C176.7 46 35.4 47.4 5.7 78.5 1.8 82.3 0 86.7 0 91.3v1.8c0 4.6 1.8 9.1 5.7 12.9 31.7 33.1 190.2 32 191.8 32H676v-11h-4v6H254v-5.2s-1.8-.9-5.8-.9h-.2l-.9.2c-3.5.2-5 .9-5 .9v2.4l-2 1.5v4.1h-24v-4.4l-2-1.2v-2.5s-2.4-.9-6-.9h-.9c-4 0-6 .9-6 .9v5.1h-4.1c-2.2 0-38.2.7-78.9-2.6v-27.9l-7.5-.5h.3-.3s-5.1-.4-9.7 1.5v11c0 9-1.8 8-14 7.3v9.1c-35.1-4.6-67.5-12.2-80.1-25.4-3.6-3.8-5.9-8-5.9-12.4v-1.8c0-4.4 2.3-8.6 5.9-12.4C19.5 65.7 51.9 58 87 53.4v9.7c12.2-1.3 14-1.6 14 7.3v13.3c4.4 1.8 9.4 1.5 9.4 1.5l7.6-.9V54.2c35.6-2.9 67.7-3.1 76.9-3.1H202v1h-22v17.4l.2.3c.2.2 3.7 3.1 13.4 3.1 8.2 0 12.6-2 14.1-2.7l1.4-.3V57.3c3.7 0 6-.9 6-.9V54l1-1.5V48h24v4.4l2 1.6v2.1s1.6.7 5 .9h1.5c4 0 5.5-.9 5.5-.9V51H578v26h94V57h4V46H195.5zm66.5 1h38v3h-38v-3zm60 0h32v3h-32v-3zm47 0h38v3h-38v-3zm56 0h37v3h-37v-3zm53 0h38v3h-38v-3zm55 0h38v3h-38v-3zm-371 .1v3.8c-15 .5-23.9 1.2-37 2.3v-3.5c13.1-1.1 25.4-1.8 38-2.2zm-44.7 7.2l.1 29.4-5.4.6V54.7c2-.2 3.2-.3 5.3-.4zm-5.3 48.4l5.4.4-.1 27.1c-2-.2-3.2-.3-5.3-.5v-27zm7 28.7c13.1.9 24.7 1.3 36 1.9v3.1c-11.3-.4-22.9-1.1-36-2.2v-2.8zm54 2.3c15 .4 23.6.4 24 .4v3.3c-1.1 0-9.6 0-24-.4v-3.3zm89 .3h37v3h-37v-3zm160-.4h39v3.4h-39v-3.4zm-53 .4h38v3h-38v-3zm108 0h38v3h-38v-3zm55 0h38v3h-38v-3z" fill="#C6CBCF"></path>
   <path d="M94 92.7c0 21.2 0 27.6-7.5 27.6-12 0-51.5-2-51.5-27.6C35 68 71 65.1 86.5 64.9c7.5 0 7.5 6.4 7.5 27.8zm-59.5 0c0 26.1 39.8 28.3 52 28.3 8 0 8-6.6 8-28.3 0-21.7 0-28.3-8-28.3-15.7.2-52 3.1-52 28.3zM608.8 103H672v30h-63.2v-30z" fill="#C6CBCF"></path>
   <use xlink:href="#scheme_91s_svg__geo-table" width="14" height="33" x="-7" y="-16.5" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 163.9 117.8)"></use>
   <g class="scheme_91s_svg__s-cell scheme_91s_svg__s-type-seatrot available">
      <use xlink:href="#scheme_91s_svg__geo-seat" class="scheme_91s_svg__cell-back" width="20" height="19" x="-10" y="-9.5" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 376.3 61.5)"></use>
      <text class="scheme_91s_svg__s-number" transform="translate(369.3 64.4)">19</text>
      <use xlink:href="#scheme_91s_svg__geo-seatrot" width="34.9" height="18" x="-17.4" y="-9" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 376.3 68.8)"></use>
      <title>
         <span>
            from 123456789
           <image xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg width=&quot;100&quot; height=&quot;100&quot;&gt;
   &lt;circle cx=&quot;50&quot; cy=&quot;50&quot; r=&quot;40&quot; stroke=&quot;green&quot; stroke-width=&quot;4&quot; fill=&quot;yellow&quot; /&gt;
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
&lt;/svg&gt; " />
           
           <g>
<svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg> 
           <g>
           
           
            до 10538.9 
            <svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg> 
            Одиночное, по ходу (сидячие)
         </span>
      </title>
   </g>
   <path fill="#C6CBCF" d="M674.2 60h5.8v64h-5.8z"></path>
   <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#B0B7BC" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M172.5 59.5h-.5c-.6 0-1.1.7-1.1 1.6v9.4c0 .9.5 1.6 1.1 1.6h.5c.6 0 1.1-.7 1.1-1.6v-9.4c0-.8-.5-1.6-1.1-1.6zM126.3 59.5h-.5c-.6 0-1.1.7-1.1 1.6v9.4c0 .9.5 1.6 1.1 1.6h.5c.6 0 1.1-.7 1.1-1.6v-9.4c0-.8-.5-1.6-1.1-1.6z"></path>
   <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#B0B7BC" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M128.7 76.3c-1.2 0-2.1-1-2.1-2.1V57.3h45.3v17c0 1.2-1 2-2.1 2h-41.1z"></path>
   <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#B0B7BC" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M171.8 57.7v-.5c0-1.3-1.1-2.3-2.5-2.3H129c-1.4 0-2.5 1-2.5 2.3v.5c0 1.3 1.1 2.3 2.5 2.3h40.3c1.4 0 2.5-1 2.6-2.3z"></path>
   <path fill="none" stroke="#C6CBCF" d="M110.4 83.2v20.7"></path>
   <path fill="none" stroke="#3385B3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M198.7 42.8c1 0 1.8.8 1.8 1.84v95c0 1-.8 1.8-1.8 1.8h-36.2l-2.7 2.9-2.7-2.9h-32.9c-1 0-1.8-.8-1.8-1.8v-95c0-1 .8-1.8 1.8-1.8l74.5-.04h0z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: this is not a valid code. You are trying to add a `<span>` to a `<title>` and then you try to add the `<svg>` to the span. The  `<span>` is an html tag. You can't add html tags to an svg element unless you put them inside a `<foreignObject>`

Comment: Please read about nested svg

Answer (score 1):

```css
.show-on-hover {
    display: none;
}
.hover-element:hover .show-on-hover {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 680 183">
   <defs>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-seat" viewBox="-10 -9.5 20 19">
         <path stroke="#5E6870" d="M5.5-7h-12c-1.7 0-3 1.3-3 3v8c0 1.7 1.3 3 3 3H5.6L5.5-7z"></path>
         <path fill="#C6CBCF" stroke="#5E6870" d="M7.5 7a2 2 0 002-2V-5a2 2 0 00-2-2h-2V7h2zM5.5 7h-11a2 2 0 002 2h7a2 2 0 002-2zM5.5-7h-11a2 2 0 012-2h7a2 2 0 012 2z"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-seatrot" viewBox="-17.4 -9 34.9 17.9">
         <path fill="none" stroke="#3385B3" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M14.5 6.6C14.5-1.4 8-8 0-8S-14.5-1.4-14.5 6.6"></path>
         <path fill="#3385B3" d="M-17.4 6l2.9 3 2.9-3zM11.6 6l2.9 3 2.9-3z"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-luggage" viewBox="-12.5 -11 25 22">
         <path d="M-11.5 7c-.7-.6-1-2-1-2.9V-7.8c0-.9.3-1.6 1-2.3.6-.6 1-.9 1.9-.9h.9V8H-10c-.9 0-.9-.4-1.5-1zM3.4 8h-6.8v1.5h6.8V8zm1.5.7c0 1.3-1 2.3-2.3 2.3h-5.3C-4 11-5 10-5 8.7V8h-2.3v-18.9H7.2V8H4.9v.8zM11.5 7c-.6.6-1.8.9-2.7.9h-.1v-18.3l.9-.6c.9 0 1.3.3 1.9.9.6.6 1 1.4 1 2.3V4.1c0 .9-.3 2.3-1 2.9z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-wardrobe" viewBox="-14.2 -10 28.4 20">
         <path d="M0-.4L-11.3-5c-.7-.3-1.1-1.3-1.1-2 0-.9.8-1.7 1.7-1.7h21.4c1 0 1.7.8 1.7 1.7 0 .7-.4 1.7-1.1 2L0-.4zM10.7-10h-21.4c-1.9 0-3.5 1.5-3.5 3.4 0 1.4 1.1 2.7 2.4 3.2L-.7 1.1v3h.9c1.2 0 1.9.9 1.9 2.1 0 1.2-1 2-2.1 2-1.2 0-2.1-.9-2.1-2.1h-1.8c0 2.1 1.7 3.8 3.9 3.8 2.1 0 3.7-1.5 3.7-3.6 0-1.8-1.3-3.3-3-3.7V1.1l11.1-4.5c1.3-.5 2.4-1.8 2.4-3.2 0-1.9-1.6-3.4-3.5-3.4z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-conf" viewBox="-24 -64.4 44 20.6">
         <path d="M-3.5-45.5c-2-2-2-5.2 0-7.2 1.7-1.7 4.2-1.9 6.2-.8.8-.6 1.6-.7 2.2-.6.2 0 .2.3.1.4-.5.3-.9.8-1 1.2h.1c1.8 2 1.7 5.1-.2 7-2.2 2-5.4 2-7.4 0zm5.9-4.2c-.3 0-.6.3-.6.6s.3.6.6.6.6-.3.6-.6-.3-.6-.6-.6zm-2.3 0c-.3 0-.6.3-.6.6s.3.6.6.6.6-.3.6-.6-.3-.6-.6-.6zm-2.3 0c-.3 0-.6.3-.6.6s.3.6.6.6.6-.3.6-.6-.3-.6-.6-.6z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
         <path d="M1.9-60.3c-.4-.4-.7-.9-.7-1.4v-2.7h8.2l.8 3.7c-1.6 2.3.1 2.4.4 2.4.3 0 2.1-.1.4-2.4l.8-3.7H20v2.7c0 .6-.3 1.1-.7 1.4-2.4 2-5 3.3-5.5 3.5-.1 0-.1.1-.1.2v3.7c.5.3.8.9.8 1.5v3.9c0 1.9-1.6 3.5-3.5 3.5h-.8c-1.9 0-3.5-1.6-3.5-3.5v-3.9c0-.6.3-1.1.8-1.5v-3.7c0-.1 0-.1-.1-.2-.5-.2-3.1-1.5-5.5-3.5z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
         <path d="M-.4-45.5c-2 2-5.2 2-7.2 0-1.9-1.9-2-5-.2-7h.1c-.2-.4-.5-.9-1-1.2-.2-.1-.1-.3.1-.4.6-.1 1.4 0 2.2.6h0c2-1.1 4.5-.9 6.2.8 1.8 2 1.8 5.2-.2 7.2z" fill="#fff" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#3385b3"></path>
         <path d="M-5.8-60.3c-2.4 2-5 3.3-5.5 3.5-.1 0-.1.1-.1.2v3.7c.5.3.8.9.8 1.5v3.9c0 1.9-1.6 3.5-3.5 3.5h-.8c-1.9 0-3.5-1.6-3.5-3.5v-3.9c0-.6.3-1.1.8-1.5v-3.7c0-.1 0-.1-.1-.2-.5-.3-3.1-1.6-5.5-3.5-.4-.4-.7-.9-.7-1.4v-2.7h8.2l.8 3.7c-1.6 2.3.1 2.4.4 2.4.3 0 2.1-.1.4-2.4l.8-3.7h8.2v2.7c0 .6-.2 1.1-.7 1.4z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
         <path d="M-6.3-48.5c.3 0 .6-.3.6-.6s-.3-.6-.6-.6-.6.3-.6.6.3.6.6.6zM-4-48.5c.3 0 .6-.3.6-.6s-.3-.6-.6-.6-.6.3-.6.6.3.6.6.6zM-1.7-48.5c.3 0 .6-.3.6-.6s-.3-.6-.6-.6-.6.3-.6.6.3.6.6.6z" fill="#fff" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#3385b3"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-exit" viewBox="-6.3 -8.7 12.7 17.3">
         <path fill="#3385B4" d="M-2.5 2.3h-3.8L0 8.7l6.3-6.3H2.5v-11h-5V2.3z"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-table" viewBox="-7 -16.5 14 33">
         <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#C6CBCF" d="M0 15.5c2.5 0 6-2 6-4v-27H-6v27c0 1.9 3.5 4 6 4z"></path>
      </symbol>
      <style>.scheme_91s_svg__s-cell{cursor:pointer}.scheme_91s_svg__cell-back{fill:#fff;stroke:none}text{font-family:Tahoma;font-weight:700;font-size:8px;fill:#807e7e}</style>
   </defs>
   <path fill="none" stroke="#C6CBCF" d="M247.5 56.6v70.8M208.5 56.6v70.8"></path>
   <path d="M94 92.7c0 21.2 0 27.6-7.5 27.6-12 0-51.5-2-51.5-27.6C35 68 71 65.1 86.5 64.9c7.5 0 7.5 6.4 7.5 27.8zM11.9 107c-1.5-1.5-2.7-6.8-3.1-8.4 1.6.7 7.1 3.1 14.4 5.7 1.1 1.8 5.1 6.9 6.4 8.8-3.1-.8-15.5-3.7-17.7-6.1zm18.8 6.6v-.2c-.2 0-5.8-7.5-6.9-9.5l-.2-.2c-8.8-2.9-15.2-5.9-15.2-5.9h-.2L8 98c0 .4 1.5 7.5 3.3 9.5 2.9 2.7 18.3 6.2 19 6.4l.4-.2v-.1zM11.7 77.4c2.2-2.4 14.6-5.3 17.9-6-1.5 1.8-5.5 6.9-6.4 8.8-7.3 2.6-13 4.9-14.6 5.7.3-1.8 1.6-7.1 3.1-8.5zm11.7 3.3l.2-.2c1.1-2 6.8-9.3 6.9-9.5v-.4h-.4c-.5 0-16.1 3.5-18.8 6.2-1.8 2-3.3 9.1-3.5 9.5l.2.2.2.2c.2-.2 6.4-3.1 15.2-6z" fill="#C6CBCF"></path>
   <path d="M74.1 122.1c0-.2 0-.2-.2-.2-15.5 0-51.7-10.1-51.7-29.2 0-18.6 34.1-29.1 51.7-29.2.2 0 .2-.2.2-.4s0-.2-.2-.2c-14.4 0-52.2 9.5-52.2 29.8 0 19.6 36.5 29.8 52.2 29.8.2 0 .2-.2.2-.4z" fill="#C6CBCF"></path>
   <path d="M195.5 46C176.7 46 35.4 47.4 5.7 78.5 1.8 82.3 0 86.7 0 91.3v1.8c0 4.6 1.8 9.1 5.7 12.9 31.7 33.1 190.2 32 191.8 32H676v-11h-4v6H254v-5.2s-1.8-.9-5.8-.9h-.2l-.9.2c-3.5.2-5 .9-5 .9v2.4l-2 1.5v4.1h-24v-4.4l-2-1.2v-2.5s-2.4-.9-6-.9h-.9c-4 0-6 .9-6 .9v5.1h-4.1c-2.2 0-38.2.7-78.9-2.6v-27.9l-7.5-.5h.3-.3s-5.1-.4-9.7 1.5v11c0 9-1.8 8-14 7.3v9.1c-35.1-4.6-67.5-12.2-80.1-25.4-3.6-3.8-5.9-8-5.9-12.4v-1.8c0-4.4 2.3-8.6 5.9-12.4C19.5 65.7 51.9 58 87 53.4v9.7c12.2-1.3 14-1.6 14 7.3v13.3c4.4 1.8 9.4 1.5 9.4 1.5l7.6-.9V54.2c35.6-2.9 67.7-3.1 76.9-3.1H202v1h-22v17.4l.2.3c.2.2 3.7 3.1 13.4 3.1 8.2 0 12.6-2 14.1-2.7l1.4-.3V57.3c3.7 0 6-.9 6-.9V54l1-1.5V48h24v4.4l2 1.6v2.1s1.6.7 5 .9h1.5c4 0 5.5-.9 5.5-.9V51H578v26h94V57h4V46H195.5zm66.5 1h38v3h-38v-3zm60 0h32v3h-32v-3zm47 0h38v3h-38v-3zm56 0h37v3h-37v-3zm53 0h38v3h-38v-3zm55 0h38v3h-38v-3zm-371 .1v3.8c-15 .5-23.9 1.2-37 2.3v-3.5c13.1-1.1 25.4-1.8 38-2.2zm-44.7 7.2l.1 29.4-5.4.6V54.7c2-.2 3.2-.3 5.3-.4zm-5.3 48.4l5.4.4-.1 27.1c-2-.2-3.2-.3-5.3-.5v-27zm7 28.7c13.1.9 24.7 1.3 36 1.9v3.1c-11.3-.4-22.9-1.1-36-2.2v-2.8zm54 2.3c15 .4 23.6.4 24 .4v3.3c-1.1 0-9.6 0-24-.4v-3.3zm89 .3h37v3h-37v-3zm160-.4h39v3.4h-39v-3.4zm-53 .4h38v3h-38v-3zm108 0h38v3h-38v-3zm55 0h38v3h-38v-3z" fill="#C6CBCF"></path>
   <path d="M94 92.7c0 21.2 0 27.6-7.5 27.6-12 0-51.5-2-51.5-27.6C35 68 71 65.1 86.5 64.9c7.5 0 7.5 6.4 7.5 27.8zm-59.5 0c0 26.1 39.8 28.3 52 28.3 8 0 8-6.6 8-28.3 0-21.7 0-28.3-8-28.3-15.7.2-52 3.1-52 28.3zM608.8 103H672v30h-63.2v-30z" fill="#C6CBCF"></path>
   <use xlink:href="#scheme_91s_svg__geo-table" width="14" height="33" x="-7" y="-16.5" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 163.9 117.8)"></use>
   <g class="scheme_91s_svg__s-cell scheme_91s_svg__s-type-seatrot available">
   <g class="hover-element">
      <use xlink:href="#scheme_91s_svg__geo-seat" class="scheme_91s_svg__cell-back" width="20" height="19" x="-10" y="-9.5" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 376.3 61.5)"></use>
      <text class="scheme_91s_svg__s-number" transform="translate(369.3 64.4)">19</text>
      <use xlink:href="#scheme_91s_svg__geo-seatrot" width="34.9" height="18" x="-17.4" y="-9" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 376.3 68.8)"></use>
       <g>
 <svg width="100" height="100" x="250" class="show-on-hover">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg> 
           <g>
      </g>
           <image xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg width=&quot;100&quot; height=&quot;100&quot;&gt;
   &lt;circle cx=&quot;50&quot; cy=&quot;50&quot; r=&quot;40&quot; stroke=&quot;green&quot; stroke-width=&quot;4&quot; fill=&quot;yellow&quot; /&gt;
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
&lt;/svg&gt; " />
           
          
           
           
           
   </g>
   <path fill="#C6CBCF" d="M674.2 60h5.8v64h-5.8z"></path>
   <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#B0B7BC" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M172.5 59.5h-.5c-.6 0-1.1.7-1.1 1.6v9.4c0 .9.5 1.6 1.1 1.6h.5c.6 0 1.1-.7 1.1-1.6v-9.4c0-.8-.5-1.6-1.1-1.6zM126.3 59.5h-.5c-.6 0-1.1.7-1.1 1.6v9.4c0 .9.5 1.6 1.1 1.6h.5c.6 0 1.1-.7 1.1-1.6v-9.4c0-.8-.5-1.6-1.1-1.6z"></path>
   <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#B0B7BC" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M128.7 76.3c-1.2 0-2.1-1-2.1-2.1V57.3h45.3v17c0 1.2-1 2-2.1 2h-41.1z"></path>
   <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#B0B7BC" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M171.8 57.7v-.5c0-1.3-1.1-2.3-2.5-2.3H129c-1.4 0-2.5 1-2.5 2.3v.5c0 1.3 1.1 2.3 2.5 2.3h40.3c1.4 0 2.5-1 2.6-2.3z"></path>
   <path fill="none" stroke="#C6CBCF" d="M110.4 83.2v20.7"></path>
   <path fill="none" stroke="#3385B3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M198.7 42.8c1 0 1.8.8 1.8 1.84v95c0 1-.8 1.8-1.8 1.8h-36.2l-2.7 2.9-2.7-2.9h-32.9c-1 0-1.8-.8-1.8-1.8v-95c0-1 .8-1.8 1.8-1.8l74.5-.04h0z"></path>
</svg>
```

you can use css or javascript to show/hide the elements. i hope this would be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include a whole SVG. Just include the `<circle>`.

```css
.hoverable:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 680 183">
   <defs>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-seat" viewBox="-10 -9.5 20 19">
         <path stroke="#5E6870" d="M5.5-7h-12c-1.7 0-3 1.3-3 3v8c0 1.7 1.3 3 3 3H5.6L5.5-7z"></path>
         <path fill="#C6CBCF" stroke="#5E6870" d="M7.5 7a2 2 0 002-2V-5a2 2 0 00-2-2h-2V7h2zM5.5 7h-11a2 2 0 002 2h7a2 2 0 002-2zM5.5-7h-11a2 2 0 012-2h7a2 2 0 012 2z"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-seatrot" viewBox="-17.4 -9 34.9 17.9">
         <path fill="none" stroke="#3385B3" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M14.5 6.6C14.5-1.4 8-8 0-8S-14.5-1.4-14.5 6.6"></path>
         <path fill="#3385B3" d="M-17.4 6l2.9 3 2.9-3zM11.6 6l2.9 3 2.9-3z"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-luggage" viewBox="-12.5 -11 25 22">
         <path d="M-11.5 7c-.7-.6-1-2-1-2.9V-7.8c0-.9.3-1.6 1-2.3.6-.6 1-.9 1.9-.9h.9V8H-10c-.9 0-.9-.4-1.5-1zM3.4 8h-6.8v1.5h6.8V8zm1.5.7c0 1.3-1 2.3-2.3 2.3h-5.3C-4 11-5 10-5 8.7V8h-2.3v-18.9H7.2V8H4.9v.8zM11.5 7c-.6.6-1.8.9-2.7.9h-.1v-18.3l.9-.6c.9 0 1.3.3 1.9.9.6.6 1 1.4 1 2.3V4.1c0 .9-.3 2.3-1 2.9z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-wardrobe" viewBox="-14.2 -10 28.4 20">
         <path d="M0-.4L-11.3-5c-.7-.3-1.1-1.3-1.1-2 0-.9.8-1.7 1.7-1.7h21.4c1 0 1.7.8 1.7 1.7 0 .7-.4 1.7-1.1 2L0-.4zM10.7-10h-21.4c-1.9 0-3.5 1.5-3.5 3.4 0 1.4 1.1 2.7 2.4 3.2L-.7 1.1v3h.9c1.2 0 1.9.9 1.9 2.1 0 1.2-1 2-2.1 2-1.2 0-2.1-.9-2.1-2.1h-1.8c0 2.1 1.7 3.8 3.9 3.8 2.1 0 3.7-1.5 3.7-3.6 0-1.8-1.3-3.3-3-3.7V1.1l11.1-4.5c1.3-.5 2.4-1.8 2.4-3.2 0-1.9-1.6-3.4-3.5-3.4z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-conf" viewBox="-24 -64.4 44 20.6">
         <path d="M-3.5-45.5c-2-2-2-5.2 0-7.2 1.7-1.7 4.2-1.9 6.2-.8.8-.6 1.6-.7 2.2-.6.2 0 .2.3.1.4-.5.3-.9.8-1 1.2h.1c1.8 2 1.7 5.1-.2 7-2.2 2-5.4 2-7.4 0zm5.9-4.2c-.3 0-.6.3-.6.6s.3.6.6.6.6-.3.6-.6-.3-.6-.6-.6zm-2.3 0c-.3 0-.6.3-.6.6s.3.6.6.6.6-.3.6-.6-.3-.6-.6-.6zm-2.3 0c-.3 0-.6.3-.6.6s.3.6.6.6.6-.3.6-.6-.3-.6-.6-.6z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
         <path d="M1.9-60.3c-.4-.4-.7-.9-.7-1.4v-2.7h8.2l.8 3.7c-1.6 2.3.1 2.4.4 2.4.3 0 2.1-.1.4-2.4l.8-3.7H20v2.7c0 .6-.3 1.1-.7 1.4-2.4 2-5 3.3-5.5 3.5-.1 0-.1.1-.1.2v3.7c.5.3.8.9.8 1.5v3.9c0 1.9-1.6 3.5-3.5 3.5h-.8c-1.9 0-3.5-1.6-3.5-3.5v-3.9c0-.6.3-1.1.8-1.5v-3.7c0-.1 0-.1-.1-.2-.5-.2-3.1-1.5-5.5-3.5z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
         <path d="M-.4-45.5c-2 2-5.2 2-7.2 0-1.9-1.9-2-5-.2-7h.1c-.2-.4-.5-.9-1-1.2-.2-.1-.1-.3.1-.4.6-.1 1.4 0 2.2.6h0c2-1.1 4.5-.9 6.2.8 1.8 2 1.8 5.2-.2 7.2z" fill="#fff" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#3385b3"></path>
         <path d="M-5.8-60.3c-2.4 2-5 3.3-5.5 3.5-.1 0-.1.1-.1.2v3.7c.5.3.8.9.8 1.5v3.9c0 1.9-1.6 3.5-3.5 3.5h-.8c-1.9 0-3.5-1.6-3.5-3.5v-3.9c0-.6.3-1.1.8-1.5v-3.7c0-.1 0-.1-.1-.2-.5-.3-3.1-1.6-5.5-3.5-.4-.4-.7-.9-.7-1.4v-2.7h8.2l.8 3.7c-1.6 2.3.1 2.4.4 2.4.3 0 2.1-.1.4-2.4l.8-3.7h8.2v2.7c0 .6-.2 1.1-.7 1.4z" fill="#3385B3"></path>
         <path d="M-6.3-48.5c.3 0 .6-.3.6-.6s-.3-.6-.6-.6-.6.3-.6.6.3.6.6.6zM-4-48.5c.3 0 .6-.3.6-.6s-.3-.6-.6-.6-.6.3-.6.6.3.6.6.6zM-1.7-48.5c.3 0 .6-.3.6-.6s-.3-.6-.6-.6-.6.3-.6.6.3.6.6.6z" fill="#fff" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#3385b3"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-exit" viewBox="-6.3 -8.7 12.7 17.3">
         <path fill="#3385B4" d="M-2.5 2.3h-3.8L0 8.7l6.3-6.3H2.5v-11h-5V2.3z"></path>
      </symbol>
      <symbol id="scheme_91s_svg__geo-table" viewBox="-7 -16.5 14 33">
         <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#C6CBCF" d="M0 15.5c2.5 0 6-2 6-4v-27H-6v27c0 1.9 3.5 4 6 4z"></path>
      </symbol>

     <style>
       .scheme_91s_svg__s-cell{cursor:pointer}
       .scheme_91s_svg__cell-back{fill:#fff;stroke:none}
       text{font-family:Tahoma;font-weight:700;font-size:8px;fill:#807e7e}
     </style>
   </defs>
   <path fill="none" stroke="#C6CBCF" d="M247.5 56.6v70.8M208.5 56.6v70.8"></path>
   <path d="M94 92.7c0 21.2 0 27.6-7.5 27.6-12 0-51.5-2-51.5-27.6C35 68 71 65.1 86.5 64.9c7.5 0 7.5 6.4 7.5 27.8zM11.9 107c-1.5-1.5-2.7-6.8-3.1-8.4 1.6.7 7.1 3.1 14.4 5.7 1.1 1.8 5.1 6.9 6.4 8.8-3.1-.8-15.5-3.7-17.7-6.1zm18.8 6.6v-.2c-.2 0-5.8-7.5-6.9-9.5l-.2-.2c-8.8-2.9-15.2-5.9-15.2-5.9h-.2L8 98c0 .4 1.5 7.5 3.3 9.5 2.9 2.7 18.3 6.2 19 6.4l.4-.2v-.1zM11.7 77.4c2.2-2.4 14.6-5.3 17.9-6-1.5 1.8-5.5 6.9-6.4 8.8-7.3 2.6-13 4.9-14.6 5.7.3-1.8 1.6-7.1 3.1-8.5zm11.7 3.3l.2-.2c1.1-2 6.8-9.3 6.9-9.5v-.4h-.4c-.5 0-16.1 3.5-18.8 6.2-1.8 2-3.3 9.1-3.5 9.5l.2.2.2.2c.2-.2 6.4-3.1 15.2-6z" fill="#C6CBCF"></path>
   <path d="M74.1 122.1c0-.2 0-.2-.2-.2-15.5 0-51.7-10.1-51.7-29.2 0-18.6 34.1-29.1 51.7-29.2.2 0 .2-.2.2-.4s0-.2-.2-.2c-14.4 0-52.2 9.5-52.2 29.8 0 19.6 36.5 29.8 52.2 29.8.2 0 .2-.2.2-.4z" fill="#C6CBCF"></path>
   <path d="M195.5 46C176.7 46 35.4 47.4 5.7 78.5 1.8 82.3 0 86.7 0 91.3v1.8c0 4.6 1.8 9.1 5.7 12.9 31.7 33.1 190.2 32 191.8 32H676v-11h-4v6H254v-5.2s-1.8-.9-5.8-.9h-.2l-.9.2c-3.5.2-5 .9-5 .9v2.4l-2 1.5v4.1h-24v-4.4l-2-1.2v-2.5s-2.4-.9-6-.9h-.9c-4 0-6 .9-6 .9v5.1h-4.1c-2.2 0-38.2.7-78.9-2.6v-27.9l-7.5-.5h.3-.3s-5.1-.4-9.7 1.5v11c0 9-1.8 8-14 7.3v9.1c-35.1-4.6-67.5-12.2-80.1-25.4-3.6-3.8-5.9-8-5.9-12.4v-1.8c0-4.4 2.3-8.6 5.9-12.4C19.5 65.7 51.9 58 87 53.4v9.7c12.2-1.3 14-1.6 14 7.3v13.3c4.4 1.8 9.4 1.5 9.4 1.5l7.6-.9V54.2c35.6-2.9 67.7-3.1 76.9-3.1H202v1h-22v17.4l.2.3c.2.2 3.7 3.1 13.4 3.1 8.2 0 12.6-2 14.1-2.7l1.4-.3V57.3c3.7 0 6-.9 6-.9V54l1-1.5V48h24v4.4l2 1.6v2.1s1.6.7 5 .9h1.5c4 0 5.5-.9 5.5-.9V51H578v26h94V57h4V46H195.5zm66.5 1h38v3h-38v-3zm60 0h32v3h-32v-3zm47 0h38v3h-38v-3zm56 0h37v3h-37v-3zm53 0h38v3h-38v-3zm55 0h38v3h-38v-3zm-371 .1v3.8c-15 .5-23.9 1.2-37 2.3v-3.5c13.1-1.1 25.4-1.8 38-2.2zm-44.7 7.2l.1 29.4-5.4.6V54.7c2-.2 3.2-.3 5.3-.4zm-5.3 48.4l5.4.4-.1 27.1c-2-.2-3.2-.3-5.3-.5v-27zm7 28.7c13.1.9 24.7 1.3 36 1.9v3.1c-11.3-.4-22.9-1.1-36-2.2v-2.8zm54 2.3c15 .4 23.6.4 24 .4v3.3c-1.1 0-9.6 0-24-.4v-3.3zm89 .3h37v3h-37v-3zm160-.4h39v3.4h-39v-3.4zm-53 .4h38v3h-38v-3zm108 0h38v3h-38v-3zm55 0h38v3h-38v-3z" fill="#C6CBCF"></path>
   <path d="M94 92.7c0 21.2 0 27.6-7.5 27.6-12 0-51.5-2-51.5-27.6C35 68 71 65.1 86.5 64.9c7.5 0 7.5 6.4 7.5 27.8zm-59.5 0c0 26.1 39.8 28.3 52 28.3 8 0 8-6.6 8-28.3 0-21.7 0-28.3-8-28.3-15.7.2-52 3.1-52 28.3zM608.8 103H672v30h-63.2v-30z" fill="#C6CBCF"></path>
   <use xlink:href="#scheme_91s_svg__geo-table" width="14" height="33" x="-7" y="-16.5" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 163.9 117.8)"></use>
   <g class="scheme_91s_svg__s-cell scheme_91s_svg__s-type-seatrot available">
      <use xlink:href="#scheme_91s_svg__geo-seat" class="scheme_91s_svg__cell-back" width="20" height="19" x="-10" y="-9.5" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 376.3 61.5)"></use>
      <text class="scheme_91s_svg__s-number" transform="translate(369.3 64.4)">19</text>
      <use xlink:href="#scheme_91s_svg__geo-seatrot" width="34.9" height="18" x="-17.4" y="-9" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 376.3 68.8)"></use>
   </g>

   <circle cx="376" cy="60" r="15" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" class="hoverable" opacity="0"/>

   <path fill="#C6CBCF" d="M674.2 60h5.8v64h-5.8z"></path>
   <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#B0B7BC" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M172.5 59.5h-.5c-.6 0-1.1.7-1.1 1.6v9.4c0 .9.5 1.6 1.1 1.6h.5c.6 0 1.1-.7 1.1-1.6v-9.4c0-.8-.5-1.6-1.1-1.6zM126.3 59.5h-.5c-.6 0-1.1.7-1.1 1.6v9.4c0 .9.5 1.6 1.1 1.6h.5c.6 0 1.1-.7 1.1-1.6v-9.4c0-.8-.5-1.6-1.1-1.6z"></path>
   <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#B0B7BC" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M128.7 76.3c-1.2 0-2.1-1-2.1-2.1V57.3h45.3v17c0 1.2-1 2-2.1 2h-41.1z"></path>
   <path fill="#FFF" stroke="#B0B7BC" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M171.8 57.7v-.5c0-1.3-1.1-2.3-2.5-2.3H129c-1.4 0-2.5 1-2.5 2.3v.5c0 1.3 1.1 2.3 2.5 2.3h40.3c1.4 0 2.5-1 2.6-2.3z"></path>
   <path fill="none" stroke="#C6CBCF" d="M110.4 83.2v20.7"></path>
   <path fill="none" stroke="#3385B3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M198.7 42.8c1 0 1.8.8 1.8 1.84v95c0 1-.8 1.8-1.8 1.8h-36.2l-2.7 2.9-2.7-2.9h-32.9c-1 0-1.8-.8-1.8-1.8v-95c0-1 .8-1.8 1.8-1.8l74.5-.04h0z"></path>
</svg>
```